# Package libibumad is obsoleted by mlnx-ofa_kernel

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, rpm

I wanted to update a KVM virtualization suite (VMmanager KVM) running on CentOS 7.

The error I am getting:

```
Package libibumad-17.2-3.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by mlnx-ofa_kernel-4.3-OFED.4.3.1.0.1.1.g8509e41.3.rhel7u4.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 10:qemu-kvm-ev-2.12.0-18.el7_6.1.1.x86_64 (centos-qemu-ev)
           Requires: libibumad.so.3()(64bit)
           Available: libibumad-17.2-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libibumad.so.3()(64bit)
```

If I disable obsolete check in yum (--setopt=obsoletes=0) I get this:

```
Removing rdma-core.x86_64 0:17.2-3.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed mlnx-ofa_kernel-4.3-OFED.4.3.1.0.1.1.g8509e41.3.rhel7u4.x86_64
Removing libibumad.x86_64 0:17.2-3.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed mlnx-ofa_kernel-4.3-OFED.4.3.1.0.1.1.g8509e41.3.rhel7u4.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libibumad.x86_64 0:17.2-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libibumad.so.3()(64bit) for package: 10:qemu-kvm-ev-2.12.0-18.el7_6.1.1.x86_64
---> Package rdma-core.x86_64 0:17.2-3.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 10:qemu-kvm-ev-2.12.0-18.el7_6.1.1.x86_64 (centos-qemu-ev)
           Requires: libibumad.so.3()(64bit)
           Available: libibumad-17.2-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libibumad.so.3()(64bit)
```

I'm not sure what should I do next. Can you recommend something?
There's no newer version of mlnx-ofa_kernel or libibumad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue, this worked for me :

Download the latest .tar.gz package on mellanox official website

http://www.mellanox.com/page/products_dyn?product_family=26

> tar -xf MLNX_OFED_LINUX-4.5-1.0.1.0-rhel7.6-x86_64.tgz

add a new local repo pointing to the RPMS folder of the extracted package

> vim /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
>
> [local]
> name=Local Repo
> baseurl=file:///root/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-4.5-1.0.1.0-rhel7.6-x86_64/RPMS
> enabled=1
> gpgcheck=0

Run the update, enjoy

> yum update

Comment: Thank you, your workaround worked well! Seems like HP doesn't updated this package:  https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX-e5c1bd9bcdb648f1a25820afa4